# matrix multiplication ,which each element in this matrix is matrix too .$\mathbf P\mathbf P^H = \frac{P}{t} \mathbf I$

Tags: matrices, matrix-calculus

$\mathbf P=[\mathbf p_1, \mathbf p_2 ,... ,\mathbf p_N]$,and each $\mathbf  p_i$ is a $t \times 1 $ complex matrix,that is ,the elements in $\mathbf p_i$ are all complex number.Now,let $trace\{\mathbf P\mathbf P^H\}=P$

How do we calculate $\mathbf P\mathbf P^H$ to this answer $\frac{P}{t} \mathbf I$

I mean ,$\mathbf P\mathbf P^H = \frac{P}{t} \mathbf I$

Does anyone know how to calculate it?

Paper link: https://www.researchgate.net/publication/3319600_Training-based_MIMO_channel_estimation_A_study_of_estimator_tradeoffs_and_optimal_training_signals

$\mathbf P\mathbf P^H = \frac{P}{t} \mathbf I$ is in $(9)$

Comment: @AnuragA $\mathbf p_i$ is the element in the  $\mathbf P$,i mean, $\mathbf p_i$  is $\mathbf p_1,\mathbf p_2,...,\mathbf p_N $

Comment: Something else  should be given for the vectors $p_i$ otherwise the equality won't hold. For example, $P=\begin{bmatrix}1&0&1\\i&i&2\end{bmatrix}$, then $P^H=\begin{bmatrix}1&-i\\0&-i\\1&2\end{bmatrix}$. Then $PP^H=\begin{bmatrix}2&2-i\\2+i&6\end{bmatrix} \neq cI$.

Comment: the elements in $\mathbf p_i$ are all complex number

Comment: Every real number is a complex number: $a=a+0i$ so something is still missing :-)

Comment: i mean c=a+bi, and $a , b \neq 0$

Comment: Assuming that $t=N$, you can apply the finite-dimensional spectral theorem to prove that $\mathbf P\mathbf P^H$  is similar to $\frac{P}{t} \mathbf I$. However, in general the equality does not stand.

Comment: I think you are not getting the point. Consider, $P=\begin{bmatrix}i\\i\end{bmatrix}$, then $P^{H}=\begin{bmatrix}-i&-i\end{bmatrix}$. So $$PP^H=\begin{bmatrix}1&1\\1&1\end{bmatrix} \neq cI.$$

Comment: @AnuragA Sorry,i don't know the value in the $\mathbf p$ matrix,because the paper  didn't mention about that,i have edited the question and add the paper link

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Let $B=PP^H$, then the paper poses the following constrained optimization problem
$$\eqalign{
\min_B &\phi(B) &= {\rm Tr}\big(B^{-1}\big) \cr
{\rm st\;} &{\rm Tr}(B) &= {\cal P}
}$$
Introduce an unconstrained variable $X$, and set
$$\eqalign{
B &= \bigg(\frac{{\cal P}}{I:X}\bigg)X \quad\implies\quad
B^{-1} &= \bigg(\frac{I:X}{{\cal P}}\bigg)X^{-1} \cr
}$$ where a colon denotes the trace/Frobenius product, i.e. $\;A:B={\rm Tr}(A^TB)$

Obviously setting $A=I$ yields 
$$\eqalign{
{\rm Tr}(B)
&= I:B \cr
&= \bigg(\frac{{\cal P}}{I:X}\bigg)\big(I:X\big) = {\cal P}
}$$
meaning that $B$ defined in terms of $X$ satisfies the constraint.

Now solve the unconstrained problem
$$\eqalign{
{\cal P}\,\phi &= {\cal P}\;\,{\rm Tr}\big(B^{-1}\big) \cr
 &= (I:X)\;(I:X^{-1}) \cr
 &= (\alpha)\,(\beta) \cr
{\cal P}\;d\phi
 &= \beta\,d\alpha + \alpha\,d\beta \cr
 &= \beta\,I:dX + \alpha\,I:dX^{-1} \cr
 &= \beta\,I:dX - \alpha\,I:(X^{-1}\,dX\,X^{-1}) \cr
 &= \Big(\beta\,I - \alpha\,X^{-2}\Big)^T:dX \cr
\frac{\partial\phi}{\partial X}
 &= \frac{\;\big(\beta\,I - \alpha\,X^{-2}\big)^T}{{\cal P}} \cr
\cr
}$$
Setting the gradient to zero reveals $X$ to be a scalar multiple of the identity matrix, i.e.
$$\eqalign{
X^{-2} &= \bigg(\frac{\beta}{\alpha}\bigg)\,I = \sigma^{-2}I \quad\implies
X &= \sigma I \cr
}$$
The constrained matrix can be evaluated without knowing the precise value of the $\sigma$ scalar
$$\eqalign{
t &= {\rm Tr}(I) = I:I \cr
B &= \bigg(\frac{{\cal P}}{I:\sigma I}\bigg)\sigma I
   = \bigg(\frac{{\cal P}}{t}\bigg) I \cr
}$$
which is the paper's result.

Comment: Why is $\alpha I:dX^{-1}=-\alpha I :(X^{-1} dX X^{-1})??$

Comment: Write down the defining equation and find its differential
$$\eqalign{
I &= X^{-1}X \cr
dI &= X^{-1}dX \;+\; dX^{-1}X \cr
0 &= X^{-1}dX\,X^{-1} + dX^{-1} \cr
dX^{-1} &=  -X^{-1}dX\,X^{-1} \cr
}$$